# Headless motion planning

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it generally possible to run the motion planning tools of ROS in an completely headless manner? To be more specific, can MoveIt run without RViz interface? Virtually all launch files out there include RViz in them, and there's little to no documentation (at least to my knowledge) on how to run this without a user interface.

Is it simply not really possible to do? Or is it just not documented?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305906/headless-motion-planning/) by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2018-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Rviz` is a visualization tool so it simply reads the topic and then displays their data. `Rviz` is never mandatory such as the `Gazebo GUI`. You can launch `gazebo` simply with the process `gzserver` and it won't change anything.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-16**:
@gonzalocasas: as @Delb mentions RViz is not required at all for MoveIt. It's just a visual debugging interface.

To start MoveIt "headless" (which doesn't really make sense, as it's not an application with a UI) just leave out the line where it starts RViz from the launch file.

**Comment by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on 2018-11-02**:
Thanks folks. Of course, it was a trivial answer (or it was a silly question). I just didn't understand why most of the usually provided launch files include RViz without any arguments to disable it.